# How to show code blocks in html in a certain way using React.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to show code blocks in my react app exactly like how they have it in react routers website page, (same color scheme). How would I go about accomplishing this , I tried prettyfied from google but I kept getting an error since Im using React.js.

Here is the react router website,(how I want my code to be display, same style/color): https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is [Syntax Highlighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_highlighting). In ReactJS, there's a couple ways you can accomplish something like this:

1. Use a [syntax highlighting library from NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=syntax%20highlighting). I haven't really used any of these myself, but seeing as this is a common need in the world of programming, I have no doubt that one of these solutions will work well for what you're trying to do, with a little tweaking.
2. Use a [markdown editor library from NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=markdown%20editor&page=1&ranking=optimal). If you need something client-side (i.e. a code editor), there's a lot of user-friendly solutions out there that plug into React quite nicely.
3. Build it yourself. You might consider taking an approach of creating your [markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) editor specific to your needs. It would be a good way for you to learn some fundamentals for manipulating input.

Best of luck!